# Updating objects in ManyToMany relationship hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

My app has 2 java pojo classes linked via `ManyToMany` relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_match", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "match_id") })
    private Set<Season> followingSeason;

}
```

`Season` class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cricket_match")
public class Season implements Serializable{

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "followingSeason", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<User> user;

}
```

On the UI I have a season button clicking on it sets the season with the user. There is a pre-existing user entry as well as the season entry in the db table. Basically I am updating the user object with an additional season object info.

```
if ("true".equalsIgnoreCase(followSeason)) {
Season season = new Season(); // I cannot instantiate a new season object here as it clears all the pre-existing entries of the season row of the entered season id. Do I load the season object first & then set it with the user object?
season.setSeasonId(SeasonId);
Set<Season> seasonSet = new HashSet<Season>();
seasonSet.add(season);
loggedInUser.setFollowingSeason(seasonSet); //loggedInUser is a User object
this.myService.followSeason(loggedInUser);
```

I cannot instantiate a new season object here as it clears all the pre-existing entries of the season row of the entered season id. Do I load the season object first from the db & then set it with the user object? I am not sure would this be the correct approach.

---

```
public void followSeason(User loggedInUser){
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(loggedInUser);
    }
```

**From the logs**

```
Hibernate: delete from user_season where user_id=?
2015-12-30 18:16:03.0999 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-6 org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister – Done deleting collection
2015-12-30 18:16:04.0005 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-6 org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister – Inserting collection: [.User.followingSeason#1]
2015-12-30 18:16:04.0011 DEBUG http-bio-8080-exec-6 org.hibernate.SQL – insert into user_season (user_id, season_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user_season (user_id, season_id) values (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to load the owner of the association from the db. You can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32036409/4754790) which provides some mechanisms about how to optimize many-to-many associations.

However, I see that the `User` is actually the owner of the association, not `Season`. And it seems that your mappings are not correct: instead of `mappedBy = "followingMatch"` you probably mean `mappedBy = "followingSeason"`.

Third point, you should use plural for collections (`followingSeasons`, `users`) to make the code more readable.

Comment: well in my knowledge in a ManyToMany relationship any entity can be the owner. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You're wrong. :) Please take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional): _"If the association is bidirectional, one side has to be the owner and one side has to be the inverse end."_ If this wasn't the case, both sides would be synchronized with the database if both are loaded in the same transaction, meaning that Hibernate would try to insert the row in the association table twice.

Comment: thnx for the reply Dragan just one more question how do you determine which side is the owning side of the relationship?

Comment: The one that is defined with `mappedBy` is the inverse side, the other one is the owner.

Comment: Dragan there is another issue in the continuation of the same question has arised. Would you help? I've updated the code, the update method of hibernate is deleting the previous values from the many to many bridge table. save is giving already existing object error.

Comment: It seems that you are always setting a new `Set` to the `loggedInUser`. Add the new `Season` to the existing set: `loggedInUser.getFollowingSeason().add(season)`.